# Two goats on a sliding leash in a square garden

Tags: probability, geometry, area

I have two goat problems I am trying to figure out.  Here are my problems.

You have a square with sides of length 100 m. There are two goats and each goat is on their own diagonal on a 10 m leash that they are able to slide along their diagonal (ignore that they might tangle up where the diagonals intersect). A cabbage is thrown into the square and it could land at any point with equal probability.

(a) Find the probability that at least one goat can reach the cabbage.

(b) Find the probability that both goats can reach the cabbage.

This is what I have done for each.  I think I am correct but if anyone sees a mistake or if I am doing something wrong please let me know.  Thank you for any help.

[image]

Area of Triangle EML = $1/2*80*40 = 1600*4$ triangles $= 6400$.  Then I took the area of the whole square $(100*100 = 10000)$ and subtract $10000-6400 = 3600$ to get the area of the region the goats can cover.  So, my probability for (a) is $3600/10000 =.36$

For (b), the probability that both goats can reach the cabbage is in that square in the middle of the figure, so $20*20=400$.  That gives me a probability of $400/10000=.04$

Comment: It looks to me as though your goats’ leashes are $5\sqrt2$ meters long, not 10 meters long, but your approach looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NB: your diagram is inaccurate: you have used this flawed diagram in your answer to (a), which has thrown its answer out, but reasoned from the correct version of the diagram in (b)]

To verify your solution, I'll proceed by a different method, and see if we get to the same conclusion.

First, note that this problem is *scale invariant*, so we'll rescale such that the big square has side length $1$, so that our probabilities are exactly the areas of the relevant shapes. Now, it's also symmetrical under quarter-rotations around the central point, so we'll restrict to the lower-left quarter, then quadruple our areas.

Now, (b) is asking for exactly four times the area of the small triangle in what is now the top-right. This triangle is right-isosceles with hypotenuse $0.2$. Pythagoras then gives that the two shorter sides are each $\sqrt{0.2^2/2} = \sqrt{0.02}$, and so the area of this triangle is $\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{0.02})^2 = 0.01$, so our probability is $4 \times 0.01 = 0.04$, agreeing with your answer.

On the other hand, (a) is asking for exactly four times the area of the central strip. That rectangle differs from the rectangle of the same width extended to the corners of our small square by four small triangles ("fold in the corners"), each of which has half of the area of the triangle in (b) (so those four small triangles have combined area $0.02$). That rectangle has one side of length $0.2$, and the other is the diagonal of this quarter-square, so has length $\sqrt{2}/2$. Thus, the area of this rectangle is $0.2\sqrt{2}/2 = \sqrt{2}/10$. Subtracting those four small triangles gives the area for the central strip as $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{10} - 0.02$. The desired probability in (a) is hence $4\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{10} - 0.02\right) = \frac{10\sqrt{2}-2}{25} \approx 0.485685425$.

Your error in (a) is that triangle $EML$ does not actually have hypotenuse $80$ or altitude $40$, *contra* your diagram. Indeed, length $CL$ is actually $10\sqrt{2}\mathrm{m}$, so length $EL$ is $(100 - 20\sqrt{2})\mathrm{m}$, and length $OM$ is actually $20\sqrt{2}\mathrm{m}$, so your altitude is $\frac{1}{2}(100 - 20\sqrt{2})\mathrm{m} = (50 - 10\sqrt{2})\mathrm{m}$. Using those values in your method will give the correct answers.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense with (a).  I was wondering about that measurement being 10 root 2.  Thank you.